# Criteria to limit code populating combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a ComboBox in Excel that is getting data from a table (tblSchedule) on a sheet ("Schedule"). The list is long and I want to add a criteria to shorten it.
I've added two cells ("C6" & "C7") on current sheet ("Invite") that have a "start" and "end" date.

How would I use those two cell C6 and C7 to limit the list pulled from tblSchedule? I think a FOR EACH and NEXT are needed, but I just don't have the skill and knowhow to come up with it.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()


'Populate Combo list values

ComboBox1.ColumnCount = 3

Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Set myTable = Worksheets("Schedule").ListObjects("tblSchedule")

myArray = myTable.DataBodyRange

Dim ComboList() As String: ReDim ComboList(1 To UBound(myArray), 1 To UBound(myArray, 2))

For i = LBound(ComboList) To UBound(ComboList)
    For j = LBound(ComboList, 2) To UBound(ComboList, 2)
       ComboList(i, j) = myArray(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

ComboBox1.List = ComboList

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Populate Combo Box With Data Between Two Dates

[image]

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const DATE_COLUMN As Long = 2
    Dim ComboCols() As Variant: ComboCols = VBA.Array(1, 2, 3)
    Dim ComboColWidths() As Variant: ComboColWidths = VBA.Array(25, 75, 25)

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Validate and store the dates in variables.
    
    Dim StartDate As Variant, EndDate As Variant
    
    With wb.Sheets("Invite")
        StartDate = .Range("C6").Value
        If Not IsDate(StartDate) Then Exit Sub ' no start date
        EndDate = .Range("C7").Value
        If Not IsDate(EndDate) Then Exit Sub ' no end date
    End With
    
    ' Return the table data in an array.
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = wb.Sheets("Schedule") _
        .ListObjects("tblSchedule").DataBodyRange
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = rg.Value
    
    ' Loop through the date column
    ' and return the matching rows in a collection.
    
    Dim collRows As Collection: Set collRows = New Collection
    
    Dim sr As Long, srVal As Variant
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        srVal = sData(sr, DATE_COLUMN)
        If IsDate(srVal) Then
            If srVal >= StartDate And srVal <= EndDate Then collRows.Add sr
        End If
    Next sr
            
    If collRows.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no matching date
    
    ' Loop through the collection and copy the relevant data
    ' from the source array to the destination array.
    
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = UBound(ComboCols) + 1
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To collRows.Count, 1 To dcCount)
    
    Dim dr As Long, dc As Long
    
    For Each srVal In collRows
        dr = dr + 1
        For dc = 1 To dcCount
            dData(dr, dc) = sData(srVal, ComboCols(dc - 1))
        Next dc
    Next srVal
    
    ' Populate the combo box.
    
    With ComboBox1
        .ColumnWidths = Join(ComboColWidths, ";")
        .ColumnCount = dcCount
        .List = dData
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    Dim myTable As ListObject
    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, iR As Long
    Dim sDate, eDate
    Const DATE_COL = 1 ' Date column index in tblSchedule
    ComboBox1.ColumnCount = 3
    ' Get start date and end date
    sDate = Sheets("Invite").Range("C6")
    eDate = Sheets("Invite").Range("C7")
    Set myTable = Worksheets("Schedule").ListObjects("tblSchedule")
    myArray = myTable.DataBodyRange
    Dim ComboList() As String
    ' Tranpose row and col index
    ReDim ComboList(1 To UBound(myArray, 2), 1 To UBound(myArray))
    iR = 0
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        ' Filter date
        If myArray(i, DATE_COL) >= sDate And myArray(i, DATE_COL) <= eDate Then
            iR = iR + 1
            For j = LBound(myArray, 2) To UBound(myArray, 2)
                ComboList(j, iR) = myArray(i, j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    ' Load list
    ReDim Preserve ComboList(1 To UBound(myArray, 2), 1 To iR)
    ComboBox1.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ComboList)
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [ReDim statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/redim-statement?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)